# Newbie Question: Switch mode Power Supply Troubleshoot

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have a small 12V 3.5A switch mode power supply that fails to provide any output.  I want to learn about switch mode power supplies so I thought I'd try to repair it.

Was hoping someone might be able to suggest what to check.

**What I'v e done so far:**

I reverse engineered some of the schematic, it looks like it's the pretty standard design based on the OB2262 PWM controller, with a TL431 voltage reference and feedback via an opto-isolator.

**Symptoms and Steps**

On power on, there seems to be an initial surge upto about 10V at the output, which rapidly dies away

I can measure 240V AC coming in, and 320V DC or so across the bulk capacitor, so no problems there.

I stuck the multi meter on frequency and looked at the signal on the FET driving the transformer, expecting to see about 200kHz or so, but nothing, so it doesn't look like it's oscillating.

I powered down, shorted the caps, then checked their in circuit capacitance and ESR, nothing seems wrong there.

I checked the diode voltage drops on the pair of Schotky diodes in the output circuit, and they seem to be as expected (voltage drop one way, OL the other).

Looked the board over for obvious shorts, broken tracks, or burnt components.  Nothing appears wrong.

Checked all the other diodes in circuit, none seem shorted.

**Tried the following trick**:  With the power off, applied 12V DC to the output, and checked the voltage divider across the output.  Under these conditions I checked the voltage between the 2 resistors of the voltage divider, I got about 0.7 volts.  My reasoning here is if I vary the voltage above and below 12V, the rated output of the PSU, I might be able to see some kind of signal being sent from the opto isolator, across to the live circuit.  As far as I can see there is none, although I don't really know what I should expect to see:  a constant voltage as a corrective signal (????) because there's no actual response to the voltage being greater or less than the rated 12V (my understanding here is sketchy I know).

I believe the TL431 and the opto-isolator rarely go bad, but I will check in powered down state as much as I can.

**Any suggestions anyone?**  How do these small wall wart switch mode PSUs normally fail?

I'm really hoping I don't have to replace the OB2262 chip, because it's so small and I don't have the facilities to do it.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check that the OB2262 gets VDD supply. Sometimes the resistor that initially provides power from rectified mains to VDD may be burnt open. If the resistor is OK, perhaps the VDD filter cap is bad so there is not enough supply voltage or stored energy to start operating.

Comment: There is a book I have titled "[How to Diagnose and Fix Everything Electronic](https://www.amazon.com/How-Diagnose-Everything-Electronic-Second/dp/0071848290)" that helps me with this and I suggest.  A very frequent culprit with SMPS is one of the aluminum electrolytic capacitors.  Look for ones with a bulging top, or some dried brown stuff that looks like it leaked out.  Also, you can look at the board for signs of heat damage -- some darkening, on the top or bottom.  The FET is one of the other common culprits, because they work so hard (and the gate insulation can be so fragile).

Comment: You can also in-circuit test the ESR of the electrolytics, as they can look just fine, and still be dried-up inside due to heat of operation driving the moisture out and drying out the electrolyte.